# Emgu CV the context menu of ImageBox is missing in a WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, emgucv

I am creating a WPF project with Emgu CV camera capture.
I embedded Emgu CV ImageBox into WPF window as below

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <WinFormControls:ImageBox x:Name="imageBoxCamera" FunctionalMode="Minimum" Dock="Fill" BackColor="Blue" SizeMode="Zoom"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

But I found the context menu of ImageBox is missing.
How to recover the context menu of ImageBox in WPF project?

The context menu looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the attribute FunctionalMode="Minimum" can recover the context menu.

Comment: Close the question marking that one like a right answer.